# The Convergence of an alternating series test

Tags: convergence-divergence

Can I confirm that 
$$\sum \frac{(-5)^{n}}{n^{3}}$$ converges by the alternating series test?

Comment: No. Dirichlet conditions are violated.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: $$5^n\gt n^3,\,\,\,\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$$

Comment: It tends to zero as n tends to $$\infty$$

Comment: NO: $\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{5^n}{n^3}\ge 1.$

Comment: How is it possible? Mathematica reaffirms that the limit is infinity..

Comment: Of cause,  $\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{5^n}{n^3}=\infty\not= 0.$ Therfore you can not apply the AST for this series.

Comment: You can use [L'Hospital's Rule](http://www.google.lk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0CCYQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FL%2527H%25C3%25B4pital%2527s_rule&ei=ExsVVbD4DcqD8gWEvIGwBQ&usg=AFQjCNEEhtJgTMqCdpekQYdZw9gl-IcUMA) to evaluate this limit.

Answer (score 0):

This series doesn't converge because its n-th member
doesn't go to $0$ as $n$ goes to infinity. And it doesn't
go to $0$ because:

$|\frac{(-5)^n}{n^3}| >= 1 $ for all n

So you cannot confirm (by any test) that it converges as that's not true.

Comment: My main problem with the question on hand is having to determine whether this series converges absolutely and if it does not, what.

Comment: What I had tried to do was to use the alternating series test and letting b_n = 1/n^(3).
Then by applying the limit as n tends to infinity, the term of the series b_n tends to 0.

Comment: @guest It is even easier than what you try to prove: the given series *does not converge at all* : not absolutely, not conditionally...nothing. This, and also the other, answer explains why.

Comment: I see it! Thank you!
Easy peasy